# Elasticsearch mapper_parsing_exception

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, logstash

I am new to `elasticsearch` and trying to import json data into it. My data looks like (logstash);

```
{ "test": "lorem", "test1": "1231", "test2": "asdasda" }
{ "test": "ipsum", "test1": "5644", "test2": "ghnghn" }
...
```

I also tried some variations of it like:

```
[{ "test": "lorem", "test1": "1231", "test2": "asdasda" },
{ "test": "ipsum", "test1": "5644", "test2": "ghnn" }]
```

and:

```
{"tests":[{ "test": "lorem", "test1": "1231", "test2": "asdasda" },
{ "test": "ipsum", "test1": "5644", "test2": "ghnn" }]}
```

When I run `post` command, which is

```
"curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/_bulk" -d @test.json"
```

I am getting:

```
Warning: Couldn't read data from file "test.json", this makes an empty POST.
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to derivexcontent"}],
"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to derive xcontent"},"status":400}
```

I am also open alternative solutions with Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me that the problem is that `curl` can't find the `test.json` file which further causes errors at the POST handler upstream.

I tried with a non-existent file and got the same error from `curl`

```
$ curl -XPOST http://localhost:12345/bogus -d @bogusfile
Warning: Couldn't read data from file "bogusfile", this makes an empty POST.
```

Make sure that `curl` is actually finding the test.json file and reading data from it.

Comment: Yeah, my bad some reason curl can't find test.json.